# Join contiguous lines of natural text and leave adjacent, non-connected lines

Tags: functions, join, filter

I would like to join all lines in a file which are continuous parts of some natural language but not back-to-back lines which are two separate entities. For example:

Join:

```
There was once a man
called Bob and he lived
in France.
```

Do not join:

```
Chapter 1
The arrival
Part 1
```

I am starting to think this will only be convenient with a modern machine learning technique as otherwise there will not be enough distinguishing features in the text to make a rule-based program. The script basically has to know on a conceptual level what is a self-sufficient unit of text (i.e. a header) vs. what seems like broken natural language, including maybe that it connects to the previous or following text.

If I can train some machine learning function to detect whether or not a line should be joined with the next or previous, either a Boolean true or false or returning “join next”, “join previous” or “do not join”, how could I implement it in Vim? A function which goes through every line, calls the classifier, and calls the Vim `join` method if it passes? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a program (`naturaljoin`) that does that analysis and produce the result you need.

Then you can filter buffer contents using it:

```
:%!naturaljoin
```

Help topic `:h filter` might be worth reading. Also `:h 'formatprg'`.

PS, code formatters are very often used with this in mind, e.g. `:%!gofmt`